# Get the Name of the Soundfile which is playing

Tags: java, file, audio

I just wanted to ask if anyone has an Idea on how to get the Name of the Soundfile which is currently played for selected Outputdevice.
Anything into that Direction or if its possible in another language maybe.
Or if its impossible, just that fact. = )

So basic example would be if I play a Music File I would like to be able to see the Name of said Music File.
I dont know for example:
sysout(System.getAudioStream().getFileName());
should print me something along the Lines of the played Musicfiles or more realisticly give me some List or Array with all Musicfiles currently being played.
If its some tmpfile (i.e. when watching a youtube video) then the name of that file should appear.

Is that possible and if yes could anyone give me a hint into the right direction?

Thank you very much for your Time!

Comment: It certainly isn't possible in Java which doesn't know anything about sounds being played outside of the current JVM.

Comment: Thank you so far, well do you know an option on how or with which language I could achieve said goal?